# Using Raiserror to display a progress message

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using `RAISERROR` as a way to create a message in the Messages tab while a script is running. I'm basing the code below off of this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx), but I'm unsure how to eliminate some extraneous wording.

```
<Do some stuff>
RAISERROR (N'Running...',
           1,
           1)
           WITH NOWAIT
<Continue doing some stuff>
```

This produces something that looks very much like an error message, with a stated severity and line reference number. What I'm looking for is a way to remove those lines, so we're just left with the message "Running". This is all written for SQL 2008 R2, by the way.

Comment: Try using ``PRINT`` instead

Comment: `PRINT` is used to return a message to the application layer. Sorry, I forgot to mention that this needs to return a progress message directly to the Messages section of SSMS. Unless I can somehow make the `PRINT` command shoot to that section instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
RAISERROR (N'Running...',
           0,
           0)
           WITH NOWAIT;
```